# How to convert a negative binomial regression coefficient to an alternative effect size?

Tags: meta-analysis, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, effect-size, cohens-d

I am conducting a meta-analysis and the effect sizes are mostly Cohen's d or log odds ratios. However, a few of the effect sizes are regression coefficients obtained from negative binomial regressions. I would like to convert these negative binomial regression coefficients to Cohen's d or log odds ratios.

I would very much appreciate some advice on how to do this. I came across this Shiny App: https://stefany.shinyapps.io/RcountD/ but it requires knowledge of the original regression intercept, standard error, and dispersion, which I don't have as I'm using summary statistics. The summary statistics I have are the negative binomial regression coefficients, their standard errors, and the sample size.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can edit your post to add the summary statistics you have?

Comment: dariober, I have edited it to add the summary statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been advised by the developer of the Shiny app that it is not possible to convert negative binomial regression coefficients to Cohen's d without knowledge of the original regression intercept, standard error, and dispersion.

The answer is copied below:

"Unfortunately, since the Poisson family models are non-linear, the magnitude of the effect depends on both the effect itself and where you start (i.e., the intercept). A 5 times increase from 1 to 5 is a 4 unit change while a 5 times increase from 10 to 50 is a 40 unit change – very different! Likewise, you can’t calculate the SD for the Cohen’s d effect without the dispersion parameter."